# Get properties connected steering wheel

Tags: c++, qt5, racing

I am using C++, Qt5 and SDL in my app with a steering wheel. I need to detect properties connected a steering wheel (minimum and maximum rotation angles), but I do not know how to do this.
Steering wheel have different limits rotation angles so I can't to use constants.

Comment: What API are you using to read the steering wheel's position?

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner I use SDL